# Allow users to post links in Drupal forum posts , only after users has more then 15 posts

Tags: 7

How to do functionality like:

If authenticated users has total posts more then 15 then only they can post links in forum topics.

I have used User state module, which displays total posts by particular users.

But I want to allow users to post links only after they have posts more then 15 in Forum topics.

Comment: you want to remove the links if posted or what?

Comment: To add to @Aboodred1's question, how should posts containing urls be handled? Should form posts containing a URL cause a validation error, be stripped out, or posted without being converted into a clickable link?

Comment: hi, yes i want that user's posts containing a any URL cause a validation error or stripped out , if users has less then 15 posts in his forum topics , otherwise allow to post links in forum topics.